# urllib.request.urlretrieve not downloading files over HTTPS

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

The below URL is the download link to download a text file.
If I paste the URL in the Firefox it downloads the actual contents i.e text file. But, when used `urlretrieve` it is giving me some html source code file.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> down_link='URL' #URL is a ***HTTPS*** link to download .txt file
>>> file=urllib.request.urlretrieve(down_link)
```

this is the output I get:

```
>>>
('C:\\Users\\rakesh.j.kulkarni\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmps7559wgi'
http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x03A3C610>)
```

when opened the file I get html source file which when opened with browser it the same webpage's login form,

So i have to come up with the alternate process to do the same for time being until the problem gets resolved

```
subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", down_link])
```

I then go to downloads and work on the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of, you should import `urllib.request`, and not just urllib (in Py3).
 And you are assigning the object to a variable so its giving you the object instance as output.
Nothing wrong with that, just to give you a quick fix, try doing:

```
In [1]: import urllib.request

In [2]: down_link = "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/shipoffools/images/4/42/Surprised_Luffy.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120921134043"

In [3]: path_to_save = "../luffy.jpg"

In [4]: urllib.request.urlretrieve(down_link, path_to_save)
Out[4]: ('../luffy.jpg', <http.client.HTTPMessage at 0x47f6af0>)
```

This will work just fine, saving the image where you want.
If you dont specify the path_to_save, then thats fine too, as it will download anyways and the path will be the `tmp` directory, In your case it would be `C:\\Users\\rakesh.j.kulkarni\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\` folder.

In the case of `https` related error or any other problem, there is a cleaner way of doing it, by reading the file with `urlopen` and saving it in a file on your computer:

```
In [5]: import urllib.request as req

In [6]: down_link = "https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/shipoffools/images/4/42/
   ...: Surprised_Luffy.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120921134043"

In [7]: fname = "../luffy.jpg"

In [8]: with req.urlopen(down_link) as d, open(fname, "wb") as opfile:
   ...:     data = d.read()
   ...:     opfile.write(data)
   ...:
```

**NOTE**: This method can take some time, but works just fine for normal small files.

---

**javascript download/redirect:**  In case of the javascript or php script download, using `subprocess` to open a link in browser won't actually be dynamic code as you need to specify the path of the browser, instead you can use an pre-existing module `webbrowser`, It will automatically detect the default browser in the system and open the url.

```
import webbrowser
url = ...
webbrowser.open(url, autoraise=True) # normal
webbrowser.open_new(url)             # new window
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)         # new tab
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's a 'https' request, i tried with your method but still i am getting same file with html source in it, instead of actual text file

Comment: I don't understand why it is not working, when i get the html source, i tried to open it on web browser and it gives me the websites login page, so i came up with the different process instead , `subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", down_link])` now it downloads the text file and saves it in downloads, i then work on the file.

Comment: I am getting the same problem with both of your method, when I paste the URL in the browser it is downloading it without any problem, i suspecting that it is some kind of cookie problem.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you would have provided what kind of file you trying to download or the link, that may could've helped to get a better answer.

Comment: Its not a cookie thing, thats probably a javascript or php code for some security purpose, and you are right `urlretrieve` or `urlopen` wont work in that case, cause it will give you the raw data from that particular webpage. Using subprocess probably wont be a good idea as it wont work on other systems properly.(the path or the browser could be different), you can read the source do some `regex` to download the file with `urllib`, but if its working for you then that's fine. But if you need the `regex` and `urllib` version, then just comment the link that might help a lot.